# Troubleshoot "SSL Handshake errors" in Indy

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

I use Indy `TidHTTPServer` and `TidServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` on my server component to handle HTTPS request for command & control.
There are situations where - without any logged errors on the server - client receive an error "SSL handshake failed". I see no reasons on the server and - funny enough - fixes itself sometimes after some time.
Where can I step into the Indy components to see where the problem is? Which events can I use to maybe see something?

Update1 (29.05.2021): An exeption I found throught he handlers suggested by Remy Lebeau is "Error accepting connection with SSL. EOF was observed that violates the protocol". I still cant tell what is causing this, though...

Comment: Which versions of Indy and Delphi are you using? What does your server config look like? Are you getting an error reported in the server's OnException event? Do you have OnStatus/Ex handlers assigned to the SSLIOHandler? Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the error in action?

Comment: "_SSL handshake failed_" is a message so unspecific like "an error has happened": the client can have his own rules about what he accepts and rejects - if the server's TLS cipher or hash is considered too weak then the client may want to protect his user. A later attempt then uses a different cipher/hash and may then succeed.

Comment: RemyLebeeau: I have added the Handlers suggested by Remy and will wait for the issue to happen. I Hope I see something.... :-/
Amigo: Once this occurs, noone can connect and after some time evryone can connect again. I will look into the cipher, I found some possible issues there... THx for the hint

Answer (score 0):

I have had this (or similar) errors in the past when I forgot to put the OpenSSL dll files in the same folder as the executable. You need ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll.

You can find them on the Indy page (link at the very bottom): https://www.indyproject.org/download/ssl/

Comment: Then I would have this issue all the time, and from my experience at init of ssl. It happens during operation when other request orked perfectly fine before.